# Obfuscation .net5 project in Linux / docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, obfuscation, .net-5

I have a .net5 application which I have to obfuscate code before publishing. There are some code obfuscation tools works perfectly in windows environment such as Eazfuscator. However, now I have to deploy the project to linux environments with docker. When I try to build project with Dockerfile, since Eazfuscator only works for windows, I cannot use it. In windows, I can define a postbuild event which runs an exe for obfuscation, but I can not run these executable files in linux. So what should I do to obfuscate code after building the project in docker environment? The popular obfuscation products do not have a solution for docker. Can you please help me?

Comment: So the only issue is that these obfuscators don't run on Linux? There are obfuscators that run on Linux / .NET Core, e.g. ArmDot.

Comment: Don't build it in docker and/or use a [windows image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-base-os-images) for the build step? Not all docker images are Linux based

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to build, publish and obfuscate before running docker build.

Just obfuscate the assemblies after publishing. Then use the obfuscated output in the publish folder to build your docker image.

Do not use the docker build to compile and publish your application